# Trying to regain writing skills I lost after a writing hiatus

Tags: fiction, creative-writing, description, humor

Edit: I'm confused what I need to ask so this question can be taken off hold.

- I'm looking for help on writing descriptive language. (it no longer flows freely in my mind like it did in the past.)
- Adding a sense of humor. I'm told that my newer stuff is lacking in that and not as fun to read as the old stuff.

---

I had a long post of what led me to this point but I guess it can be summed up to I was able to think and write more coherently in high school than I can now.

I'm not fully sure how that happened. I guess anxiety and depression got the better of me after I became an adult and I can't write as well as I did. I am hoping this is a problem that can be resolved.

Based on feedback I got from my friends and family:

- I need to regain the ability to use descriptive language.
  I can occasionally describe a scene and use descriptive language. In those paragraphs where I did that, I get favorable responses, "Now you need to do more of that."
  (back then it flowed naturally. This time I have to really work to get the description.)
- I need to regain a sense of humor.
  The themes I find now as boring and trite, over the top and slapstick is what seems my readers like about my older work. The problem I have is getting back into that mindset. It feels forced vs. it being natural.

Now I am trying to get back into writing description and add a sense of humor without it feeling forced or driving me to lose interest.

(P.S.) I want to tag this subject "writing after hiatus" or "lost writing skills" but I am not allowed to tag with under 150 rep points. If someone would like to add those tags, that would be great.

Comment: this still feels a little... opinion based but I will do my best to answer objectively.

Comment: Sorry for the novel >< I just feel like I can relate to you a bunch so I hope you find what I have to say useful!

Comment: Please do not react to the closure of a question by deleting it and asking the same question again. Take our tour https://writers.stackexchange.com/tour to see how things work around here. If you want to discuss something writing related  that does not fit our Q/A format, there is always chat. https://writers.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: I thought I did reword the question more clearly. I'm confused.

Comment: It says I can't participate in the chat yet, when I try to move the comments over.

Comment: You need to ask a specific craft question that can have an objective answer that is useful to other people. It is not about how you ask the question. It is about the type of question you ask.

Comment: Do other people have the issue I am asking? Maybe it will help them too? I'm bad at this. I have another question, but I am not sure if it will too end up on hold. "How to write emotion into a scene?"

Comment: Ask it and see. But take the tour first and try to get an idea of what is and is not appropriate around here. You would not be the first person to have their first question put on hold. This place is different from most sites. At its best it works well, but it is not the place for everything. It is not a forum or a chat room. It is about specific limited questions to which there can be specific objective answers. Those kinds of questions can be part of your journey, but they won't be all of it. Try to ask the kinds of questions that fit the format. But start by taking the tour.

Comment: I believe I understand your question and that it is common and has an answer. I believe the way we write when we are young *is* trite & self indulgent & awful. But I also believe that other young people (and some older people) like it, for its grittiness or something. I believe that as we age we shift into wanting to impart something that is less about shared angst and more about lessons learned.  Because of this shift, I think humor & description may change. It may be inappropriate even to be humorous in what you are writing now. (You can learn tools to describe on various websites. though.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to regain the ability to use descriptive language. I can occasionally describe a scene and use descriptive language. In those paragraphs where I did that, I get favorable responses, "Now you need to do more of that." (back then it flowed naturally. This time I have to really work to get the description.)

This is because you are trying too hard to be who you used to be. The moments where people say YES THAT'S IT! are the times you get into a groove and you stop thinking, you are just writing. Everyone changes. There are many things I wish I can be from my high school days, but we cannot go back to who we were. You may actually realize that you cannot write comedy anymore in general because your view on life has changed and that is perfectly okay.

I had a friend who used to be able to take any song we threw at him and make some improv up about someone sitting at our lunch table. He can no longer do this, at least not on the fly like he used to.

> I need to regain a sense of humor. The themes I find now as boring and trite, over the top and slapstick is what seems my readers like about my older work. The problem I have is getting back into that mindset. It feels forced vs. it being natural.

This is probably due to your depression. I, like many here, have suffered from this. One of the worst things about depression is that even life's greatest pleasures become mundane. Finding something you are passionate about while depressed is hard, especially when you want to pick up an old interest. I personally would love to go back to my old hobbies... Sports and piano specifically, but no matter how many times I sit at the keys, the music doesn't come. I can feel the music still and the emotions are there, but the music won't play. I found that while I do want to learn to play piano again, I don't have the drive to play like I once did and that is okay.

You will find that as we age, as we get older, things that interested us before, do not anymore. We grow different tastes as we experience life. If you asked the high school me if they would attempt to write a book in 10 years, they would laugh and say ya right, I will be a civil engineer who is married and playing in adult league sports.

I am not saying that you should quit trying to write, on the contrary, I encourage you to continue. I actually started writing because my therapist said it could be therapeutic for me. Is my writing darker or maybe more serious? Probably because I am putting my emotions and struggles into the book to let go of the anger pent up inside.

The first step to making progress is recognizing where you currently are, not where you were or where you want to be. The cliche advice is to just write. Write everything and anything even on days you don't feel like writing. This has merit for sure. You want to stop trying to think and control the words and let it flow.

Like playing the piano, if you force the keys, it will sound forced. If you try to control the song, it will not feel right. However, if you just close your mind, and let your emotions play the piece, you will be amazed at how little it takes to play something so simple but yet so amazing.

Some of the best piano pieces and considered classics are also some of the most simple pieces you will hear, lacking many intricacies that you think would define a professional. This too works in writing. It's not about using the big words, the fancy words, the complex sentences. Good writers use simple words and why they say the lower the reading grade level, the better off you are.

So keep practicing, don't think just write. Feel the story. Write side stories, and listen to current comedy. What did you like? what did you not like? was it their delivery of an old joke? Or was it that they wrote a skit about a life event that you can relate to and that made it even funnier? Once you recognize WHY you find jokes funny, you can use that to influence your own jokes.

Sorry for writing you a novel, I hope you and others will take the time to read it. I understand completely where you come from all too well and the best advice I can give is to just not give up if it is something you truly want. Just don't try too hard as that will end up causing you to be discouraged when you feel it does not come out well.

PS Try to read over the parts that people say are great. Ask why do they say it's great! See what makes those parts stand out from the rest. Remember what you were thinking and feeling at those times you were writing those parts. Maybe find someone who won't critize your work initially but rather compliment to boost your confidence. I know for me that helped when later on I sought real critizism. But the initial confidence booster gave me the ability to write more relaxed and more fluid.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write! My friend asked why are you so into writing this now? I gave my reasons, that I finally feel I got the series plotted out and the theme is relevant to our culture (the theme has evolved into questioning the trend towards nationalism "Our colony first" vs the need to see other cultures and team with them to fight bigger issues.) The premise of the series shifted.

Comment: I have to remember line breaks don't work in comments. After I listed my reasons I said I fear I'll lose interest again. He said this so far has been the thing I've been the most focused on since he's known me. But I know myself that the momentum I have, no matter how intense it is, I can lose it just as quickly. It is frustrating, because I don't "master" a skill. I get to a point and then switch off to another thing.

Comment: @BugFolk I am the same way dude, same way. Writing is a commitment. One that takes a lot out of you and requires a lot of focus. But I have a story to tell. My story. It's a story that takes my online persona and a world that I have been living in my head for the last 10 years and I am putting it on paper for the world to read. I want the world to read it. I want the story to end too. So that I can move on in my life. I feel like I can do that once I finish writing the story to my online persona that I have been for the last 10 years.

Comment: That's what keeps me moving forward. Knowing that the end of the story will also be the end of the online personality that I have been (in a poetic fate that the MC ends up dying in the end) as a way to release me from my past to start new. Maybe you can do the same with your story, or maybe you don't have the same type of motivation as I do. But know that your story i am sure many will want to read with the current world situation. Tell your story in your eyes the story you want people to know :)

Comment: That might be it, the difference between me writing back in grade school/ high school. The purpose was to entertain myself and my little sister. But as an adult now I see something that struck my beliefs and now the focus is like yours, I now feel i *must* tell it or at least set up a situation that explores sides of it and leaves the reader to ask themselves questions. Are they both right? Or both wrong. Or rather a bit of gray between those two extremes.

Comment: @BugFolk What about writing it as if you are writing it for your sister? but you want to expose the world from your beliefs to her so that you can "warn her" or what ever it is that you are trying to do? I don't write as if I am writing for the world even though that is ultimately what I want to do. I write because I have 3 friends who keep bugging me when my next chapter is finished so they can keep reading. Writing for that enjoyment of friends helps to keep the pressure off and make me just write. Maybe you can find people who can provide that type of support?

Comment: Though the new series borrows characters from my old works, it is in fact a different story. But because it is different, it explores areas I'm not as experienced in. I read over the old 2003 draft dealing with my soldier characters. Maybe it worked because it was so bad, it was funny and flowed with the rest of the story that was just as extreme. Going towards a more realistic theme, now the lack of experience shows for what it is.

Comment: @BugFolk you got to decide then, if you want to be over the type and slapstick, or if you want to be realistic. Being over the top and slapstick means that it doesn't have to be accurate or realistic. They are satire/exaggerations of the topic to make it funny. If you want it to be realistic, you may have to do research on some subjects you lack experience in. I know I spent 6 months in google before writing a single word of my novel just to make sure I built my world correctly.

Comment: My sister is grown up now. I'd be writing for my niece. :) I can explore that idea. Perhaps if I get stuck again. Right now I'm teetering on the climax of the story (with the excerpt in my other post) and man, why the climax do I lose momentum? I have it mapped out. I know what will happen. It's like my dad says about being in the end zone ready to do a touchdown. Just get the ball in. Yet I...

Comment: Yeah that may be it. I am writing about soldiers in my fictional story. They are bugs, so I feel tricked into believing realism isn't as important, but yet my readers are quick to remind me even in that case there are limits to suspension of disbelief. So I might have to bite the bullet, pick a time I am in a writers block and read war stories to get an idea on perspective.

Comment: See maybe this is where we differ. I don't have my story mapped out. On the contrary, I just know how I want it to end. I know what kind of morals I want to teach, the lasting impact I want to have. And I started with a journey on my world. I am taking the journey as if I am the MC. I am discovering my story as I write it. This makes it fun because I get to go on an adventure in my head that I put to paper. And in the end, I hope that the adventure I have in my head is fun for others too! Maybe it's that you are trying to be too rigid

Comment: It looks like I can explore two options: 1. write the realistic story. It is bad, but try not to get hung up on it until I am near done. 2. Splinter off and see if I can do anything with the older work. It would be a complete rewrite, perhaps a change in the cast of characters.  I don't see me doing 2. until I get to a stopping point with point 1.

Comment: @BugFolk instead of losely following a general plot or theme. This will have it less forced IMO to being what you have planned, and allow your freedom and creativity to flow more as you guide the story to the end result as you want to. I can't tell you how many times my plot has shifted.

Comment: 1 sounds like your best bet. But that advice is good for any writing. Just write it without being hung up until you are done, then go back, read it, edit it, fluff it up. One of the writers here had a first draft of like 120,000 words and then edited it down to 90,000 on the first edit.

Comment: I do a bit of both. I have key plot points planned out, but the a to b to c, is where I discover stuff as I write it. I know the key plots and subplots, but as I draft them out my characters do pull surprises on me. I learn as I write, but I notice that times I think I have everything, I lost interest, and then the only way I can break out of it is to purposefully change something to upset the plot when I am actually writing the story. I did that with a rescue type plot. Worked really well. Gained a new character and colony out of it too.

Comment: Considering the story I have is only 27,000 words into it and it is near done, I have room I can work in description, perhaps add scenes.  The plot of this book developed as I wrote it. I was thinking of "how my 5 year old character gets his father figure" as the main plot (and introduce the main protagonists of the series) but surprise it became a story about overcoming bullies.  I went back in and did more with the classroom bully character. I can do more with them yet.

Comment: The book I am working on now has splintered into two plots: the  5 year old character - learn to stand up to bullies. The soldier character - to overcome his regrets over the last battle, set his mindset from being cold and reckless/ruthless to a desire for redemption. The soldier's plot line extends beyond the first book. We also find out the 5 year old is on that same path, whether he knows it or not. (fantasy elements).

Comment: Where I am stuck is making a believable attempt at suicide scene and feel the emotions involved when right now I feel kind of emotionally flat. Maybe bordering on laughing.  I can't convey the emotion I want to, and that is going to hurt the next scene I want to write which is the child finding the soldier character/ his father figure passed out cold. Yeah that is pretty bad. Sometimes I imagine my finger or my shoe coming down on them in a moment of frustrated writers block......I digress